# Upload multiple files with a single input element

Tags: php

I have a simple input for "file".

I was wondering how I go about making it so you can select multiple files using one input.

```
<input name="sliderfile" id="sliderfile" type="file" />
```

Basically, multiple select in one browse window.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can without some sort of client-side scripting.

Comment: you could add more inputs for more files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `<input type="file">` with the `multiple` attribute.

```
<input name="sliderfile" id="sliderfile" type="file" multiple>
```

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MadaraUchiha/zLv8U/)**.

*Note: IE6 won't like it.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<input name="sliderfile" id="sliderfile" type="file" multiple />` though if you are considering those poor blokes using old versions of IE you may have to use JS to imitate something like this, there is a fash component that works in similar way, the component is known as swfupload, jQuery has some plugins based on it, popular one is uploadify

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="sliderfile[]" id="sliderfile" type="file" />
```

accessible with

```
$_FILES['sliderfile'][0];
$_FILES['sliderfile'][1];
$_FILES['sliderfile'][2];
```

....