# multiple image uploading using php

Tags: php, html, image

i'm trying to upload multiple files at one time but not getting proper result. my code is as follow:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['uploadfiles'])) {
    print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <input type="file" name="uploadfiles" multiple="multiple" min="1" max="999"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Upload"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

when i use print_r($_FILES) it only dispays the first selected file details. kindly help me.

Comment: ref this http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051051/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-input-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uploadfiles named as an array:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadfiles[]" multiple="multiple" min="1" max="999"/>
```